# How to slice and apply resampling on df in list comprehension in one liner in python list?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

Say a list where elements are pandas df.

```
lst = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
```

Every df is time series with DT index. `df1 & df2` have values at every 15 mins and `df3 & df4` have values at every hour. I want to concate all but before that i need to do some changes in `df3 & df4`. 
First is resampling and change the name of columns which i did with this code:

```
[df.resample('15min').bfill() for df in lst]  #this code works for all but, i want this only in df3 & df4- code 1


for df in lst[2:4]:
    df.resample('15min').bfill()              #this run but does nothing - code 2 

for df in lst[0:2]:                           #same column name for df1, df2  - code 3
    df.columns = ['heat']

for df in lst[2:4]:
    df.columns = ['energy']                  #same column name for df3, df4 - code 4
```

Do i need to make an object to save the values of 2nd code? And is there a better way to combine the  code 1,3,4 in one liner while doing slicing?
This is same as, when i want to divide every df with a value i have to give list comprehension, the for loop doesn't work.

```
lst = [x/1000 for x in lst]   #this works

for x in lst:
    x.values / 1000           #this doesn't
```

Comment: Have you noticed that everywhere you use "="  it works, and when you don't use "=" "it does nothing"?

Comment: Yeah  using this '=' , the code works, because i am saving the output in that variable. Let's say i want to combine all this in list comprehension. Is there a way to do this.

Comment: You are not re-assigning dataframes in code 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a list-comprehension for resampling you can

```
lst = [df.resample('15min').bfill() for df in lst]
```

which will not affect `df1` and `df2` since they are already 15-minutes spaced.

If you want to rename column name in one cycle:

```
for i,df in enumerate(lst):
    df.columns = ['heat'] if i<2 else ['energy']
```

I don't think you can both resample and rename columns in a single list-comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you expect that operations are done **in-place** ([here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/93996/in-place-and-out-place-sorting-meaning) is a good description of the difference).

In list comprehension the operation returns the value that is stored in a list. E.g.

For `[x/1000 for x in lst]` - `x/1000` is such an operation

If you do not **store** the result of an operation somewhere it is not going to be available (retrievable):

```
for x in lst:
    x.values / 1000
```

The result of `x.values / 1000` is not stored anywhere. However, you can place it in a different list, like this way:

```
another_list = []
for x in lst:
    another_list.append(x.values / 1000)
```

Then the results of `x.values / 1000` operation are available in `another_list` in the very same way as in `lst` list.

Therefore, the solution to the issues you have should be this:

```
for df in lst[2:4]:
    df = df.resample('15min').bfill()
```

Comment: ```another_list = []``` will be then again the list of dfs but after the values has been divided?

Comment: Yes, precisely.